# wamp Mysql console closes after entering a password

Tags: mysql, wamp, wampserver

I have just installed Wamp 2.4, but I can't get MySQL running. Wamp icon is orange. When I open MySQL console, it asks for the password, but after pressing <kbd>enter</kbd>, the console closes and pc gives me a loud beep.

After a bit of research I found some ppl with the same problem, however I couldn't find any answer. Has anybody experienced the same problem?

Answer (score 3):

If the wampmanager icon is ORANGE then one of the services wampapche(Apache) or wampmysql(MySQL) has not started.

If it is the MySQL service that is not started then the MySQL Console will not work as it has no service to talk to.

To discover what the problem is first look at the MySQL error log menu -> MYSQL -> MySQL log. If this does not exist or has no useful information then look at the Windows Event Log, Windows Start -> Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Event Viewer.
In there look in the Windows Logs -> Applications for messages from MYSQL. This should give you fairly accurate info on what the problem is.

Its also always a good idea to look for rouge `my.ini` files on your system. Do a search for `my.ini` and `my.cnf` and if you find any that exist outside the `\wamp\bin\mysql\` folder structure then delete them. If a rouge exists its probably in `C:\windows\system32` but dont rely on that being the location.

**How to tell which service is not running if the wampmanager icon is orange.**

Left click the wampmanager icon to reveal the menu-> Apache -> Service

If the 'Start resume service' menu item is Green then Apache is running.

Left click the wampmanager icon to reveal the menu-> MySQL -> Service

If the 'Start resume service' menu item is Green then MySQL is running.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's definitely MySQL, I'll try what you suggested

Answer (score 0):

i have wamp server( 3.1.4) 64-bit here its  showing green light and i have tested that no port is used still when i enter my password which is nothing at starting ,console closes automatically...i think this problem is due to windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

The default username of the wamp will be root and password will be empty(do not fill any character), simply click enter. This will do your work.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to get your MySQL console to work after hitting enter without a password or with a password, you have to uninstall it because it's not going to work.
I have tried all the ways but its not going to work for me.
Hence I uninstalled wamp and install it again now its working fine.